# Remove characters before first and after second underscore extracting string between first and second underscore

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am using

```
gsub(".*_","",ldf[[j]]),1,nchar(gsub(".*_","",ldf[[j]]))-4)
```

to create a path and filename to write to. It works fine for names in `lfd` that only have one underscore. Having a filename with another underscore further back, it cuts everything off that is in front of the second underscore.

I have for example:
`Arof_07122016_2.csv` and I want `07122016`, but I get `2`. But I don't get why this is happening. How can I use this line to only cut off the characters in fromt of the first underscore and keep the second one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you want

```
sub("^[^_]*_([^_]*).*", "\\1", ldf[[j]])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aDNw9G/2)

The pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `[^_]*` - 0+ chars other than `_`
- `_` - an underascxore
- `([^_]*)` - Capturing group #1: any 0+ chars other than `_`
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

The `\1` in the replacement pattern only keeps the captured value in the result.

[R demo](https://ideone.com/mQcApp):

```
v <- c("Arof_07122016_2.csv", "Another_99999_ccccc_2.csv")
sub("^[^_]*_([^_]*).*", "\\1", v)
# => [1] "07122016" "99999"
```

Comment: Title of the question is a bit misleading. OP wants to remove the rest of string if there are other instances of `_`. If you actually are looking for *removing characters before first _*. then this works: ```^[^_]*_(.*)```: https://regex101.com/r/B8gqIi/2

Answer (score 4):

Regular expression repetition is greedy by default, as explained in `?regex`:

> By default repetition is greedy, so the maximal possible number of
>   repeats is used. This can be changed to ‘minimal’ by appending ? to
>   the quantifier. (There are further quantifiers that allow approximate
>   matching: see the TRE documentation.)

So you should use the pattern `".*?_"`. However, `gsub` will make multiple matches so you end up with the same result. To remedy this use `sub` which will only make 1 match or specify that you want to match at the start of the string by using `^` in the regex.

```
sub(".*?_","","Arof_07122016_2.csv")
[1] "07122016_2.csv"
gsub("^.*?_","","Arof_07122016_2.csv")
[1] "07122016_2.csv"
```

Comment: *Regular expressions are greedy by default* is a wrong, or at least misleading statement. See what you yourself supplied in the quote: *By default **repetition** is greedy* - the quantifier can be greedy or lazy.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OK, I've clarified that this option is about the repetition